# error reading from the database moodle 2.8.5

Tags: moodle

I copied the moodle site from the server and set it up in the local in xampp.
I also imported the same database which was on the server.
I also did all the nessesory changes in the config.php file, but it's giving an error while reading from the database.

Please help me out with this.
I am new to the moodle.

Comment: This looks like a case for moodle's own support resources rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Looks like you didn't configure xampp correctly to connect to the DB.

Comment: I have configured the xampp correctly. I debuged the code and i came across the set.php file in this file \core\session\manager::start(); because of this line it is having error. THat means its related to the sessions. so Please help me out with this.

Comment: Did you copy the site data too? There are some instructions here for copying to another site : https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Moodle_migration